# maintain check and uncheck mark even app get closed

Tags: android

i want to make 4 different button as check and un check even after the app get closed,i am using shared preferences for that but i cant able to maintain the state,its confusing me.can anyone help me.

Thank you

```
preferences1 = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Notification_Dashboard.this);
    Boolean state_chk = preferences1.getBoolean("key", false);
    System.out.println("state_chk" + state_chk);

    if (state_chk == true) {
        msg_viewed = "0";
        message_view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notif_uncheck);
        preferences1.edit().putBoolean("key", false).commit();
    }

    else {
        msg_viewed = "1";
        message_view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notif_checked);
        preferences1.edit().putBoolean("key", true).commit();
    }
```

Comment: SharedPreferences should persist the changes. Show us the code you save and read data from it.

Comment: show some code what you have done to get a better answer...

Comment: What you have implemented ?  Please show.

Comment: Are you using checkbox ?

Comment: No i am using buttons for that

Comment: how the buttons can have checked and unchecked states?

Comment: You can not manage the checked and unchecked states on button. For that either you can use the `ToggleButton` or  `CheckBox`.

Comment: i am changing the images as check and uncheck

Comment: Please post full code. If you are changing the images for checked then how you are managing for the Unchecked buttons.

Comment: If its checkbox also it is ok for me

Comment: How you check or uncheck is not the issue. Can you post the code  where you save the status into SharedPreference? Also, in which methods of  an Activity is the above code running? OnCreate()?

Comment: @Gajendran Check out my answer and try to implement that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

For your checkbox define the checkedchanged listner as below:

```
  yourcheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                     saveCheckBox("First",true);

                } else {
                     saveCheckBox("First",false);
                }

            }
        });
```

Save checkbox value in sharedpreference

```
 public void saveCheckBox(String key, boolean isChecked){
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putBoolean(key,isChecked);
    editor.commit();
 }
```

Get the preference values

```
 public boolean getCheckBoxState(String key){
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
       prefs.getBoolean(key, false);
 }
```

In your activity `onCreate()` method try to get sharedpreference value and set the checkbox checked or uncheck as below:

```
   Boolean isCheck=getCheckBoxState("First");
   if(isCheck)
   {
      yourcheckbox.setChecked(true);
    }
   else
    {
        yourcheckbox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks.